# discord.py host vps that allow saving json files

Tags: hosting, discord.py

I'm looking for a vps to host my bot discord that saves me json file data.
I currently use Heroku as a host and it doesn't save my data so I'm looking for a VPS that allows me to do this.

Comment: Any VPS will let you store json files, think of a VPS as a remote computer. Only difference being that you access them through ssh. Host-pls, Vultur etc are just some examples. If you're paying for a vps, you can go for a real database instead of relying on JSON.

Comment: Use Google Cloud or AWS forever free tiers, you will need a credit card. That is the only way to get proper VPS for "free".

Comment: At the moment, relying on a database is the last thing I want to think about. In the future I will go through it but at the moment being new to python I would like to learn JSON better.
I'll try the free ones as you recommend using databases to pay for a VPS I'll let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For discord.py hosting I personally would use a VPS on AWS as they have a free tier that you can use to try out the VPS and everything before you actually spend money on it.

This is known as an amazon ec2 instance which the link to is --> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

AWS VPS is also very fast and offers very little latency from the servers to discord. You would normally get around 14-23 ms.

The AWS ec2 is also very easy to configure and setup through the use of free services like PUTTY and WINSCP. FileZilla is also something you can use instead of WinSCP.

***YOU WILL NEED A CREDIT CARD FOR AWS SIGNUP BTW TO MAKE SURE YOU ARE HUMAN.

Comment: I tried but couldn't set node.js. Is there any specific tutorial using discord.py?

Comment: You cannot really find a tutorial but all you have to do it transfer bot files to the server and install all of your dependencies by using commands like pip3 install discord.py. You might have some issues like pip needing to be updated or whatever but I am telling you that basically any error can be found on stackoverflow. After everything has been installed you can just run the main file of the bot like this --> python3 index.py. That will run the main file of the bot. Then if you want to close out the terminal without ending the process you can check install screen and detach that session.

Comment: I'm sending you this other post where in the end I got stuck and never continued [namely this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63600251/package-json-it-resets-every-time-i-try-to-do-pnp-install).

Comment: Don't follow that tutorial for a python bot I would recommend watching this video -->https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYvKv3kM9pk. It is not on discord but it tells you how to run a python script. Just manually install any dependencies you need by doing a command like this "pip3 install discord.py". When you follow that video just run your discord bots main file. If you have any more issues just comment.

Comment: If you liked my answer please consider marking it with a green checkmark

Comment: I had a hard time and never touched those scripts again. See you soon and I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Repl for your hosting service. It's free to use and I had no headaches while using it.

Repl Discord.py Guide: https://repl.it/talk/learn/Hosting-discordpy-bots-with-replit/11008

[image: As you can see you can add files including .json ones and still run you're bot off of Repl.]

As you can see you can add files including .json ones and still run you're bot off of Repl.

Answer (score -1):

For a discord.py hosting i would recommend you using FalixNodes, it gave you 3000MB of free RAM also alot of disk space, its easy to setup, (you must login with discord in order to create the accounts) [FalixNodes](https://falixnodes.net/) You can also store local db file right there

Comment: There's no such thin as free host, you'll only get a headache and your data will be lost.